# How to store formatted text in a database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to store a formatted text data in a database and by formatted text I mean not a rich text but newlines break and paragraph. For instance I have a text which looks like this:

**Original appearance of text with newline and paragraphs:**

Once, there lived a washer man named Bheema. He had a donkey and a horse. The donkey carried clothes to the pond and back to his house. The horse carried Bheema to the market and back, occasionally. The donkey worked much harder than the horse.

On a bright sunny day, Bheema was going to the pond with donkey. He took the horse along to give it a drink of water. The donkey was carrying a heavy load of clothes. The horse was carrying nothing. The load was unusually heavy and the donkey’s back was hurting.

When the pain became unbearable the donkey said to the horse, “This load is too much for me, brother! Please take some of this load on your back."

The horse replied some what rudely, “Eh! Why should I? I am here only to carry our master to the market." The proud horse continued on his way. The day was getting hotter as the day went on. The donkey felt totally exhausted. He was almost dragging himself. “Humph! Humph!" The donkey tried to move. He just could not. The poor donkey collapsed to the ground. “Oh! What has happened to the poor donkey?" thought the washer man.

***I have to store this into a sqlite database and display it to user exactly the same to a users.***

**Problem:** When displaying it to users all the newline are mixed up with no paragraph whatsoever. Below is the sample of my problem.

Once, there lived a washer man named Bheema. He had a donkey and a horse. The donkey carried clothes to the pond and back to his house. The horse carried Bheema to the market and back, occasionally. The donkey worked much harder than the horse. On a bright sunny day, Bheema was going to the pond with donkey. He took the horse along to give it a drink of water. The donkey was carrying a heavy load of clothes. The horse was carrying nothing. The load was unusually heavy and the donkey’s back was hurting. When the pain became unbearable the donkey said to the horse, “This load is too much for me, brother! Please take some of this load on your back." The horse replied some what rudely, “Eh! Why should I? I am here only to carry our master to the market." The proud horse continued on his way. The day was getting hotter as the day went on. The donkey felt totally exhausted. He was almost dragging himself. “Humph! Humph!" The donkey tried to move. He just could not. The poor donkey collapsed to the ground. “Oh! What has happened to the poor donkey?" thought the washer man.

How I am trying to achieve what I want:

1. I use SQlite studio for creating prepopulated database
2. I copied the original text and paste it into column of my prepopulated database. The data type of my column where I pasted the original text is TEXT
3. I fetched data from a prepopulated database into a TextView

Comment: This has nothing to do with the database. Show the code that displays the text.

Comment: @KrupalShah that is another solution. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to save it to database; you can save formatted text content in a file as html or with some markup language. and then you can save the file path for each record in db.

This is just my solution. I don't know it is good or bad; but it should work.